# trouble calculating the amount of Sundays inbetween 2 dates

Tags: python, date, datetime, calendar, logic

I was asked to create a program that calculates the number of Sundays inbetween 2 dates! I have been searching numerous articles and documentation but I still have a hard time understanding syntax. (2 months into my coding course with 0 technology and computer experience.)

I am having trouble understanding the logic of how to associate the calendar with the days inside the Dictionary. My current code is as follows :

```
def difference_between_days():
    daysDict = {0 : "Monday",1: "Tuesday",2: "Wedensday",3: "Thursday",4: "Friday",5: 
"Saturday",6: "Sunday"}

    first_date = date(2021,7,28)
    end_date = date(2022,7,28)

    difference_between_dates = end_date - first_date
    print(f"There are {difference_between_dates.days} days inbetween the two dates!")

    d = date.weekday(first_date)
    dd = daysDict[d]
    print(f"The first date selected is a : {dd}")


difference_between_days()
```

edit: When using certain functions such as .isoweekday I run into problems printing because it returns me something like this "<built-in method isoweekday of datetime.date object at 0x000001EB956FA0F0>" and I still have not reached classes yet!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember to mention your programming langauge and also add the appropriate language tag. Or we’re lost, and those knowing about Python are unlikely to find your question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is not my weapon of choice, but this should do the job.
The idea is to use weekday() to move the start date to the following sunday, and the endate to the previous sunday. Then count the days in between, divide by 7 (weeks) and add 1 because both ends are Sundays.

Don't hesitate to ask if it's not clear, and accept the answer if it it.

HTH

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 

def number_of_sundays(from_str, to_str):
    
    # get date objects from the string representations in Ymd format
    from_date = datetime.strptime(from_str, "%Y/%m/%d")
    to_date = datetime.strptime(to_str, "%Y/%m/%d")

    # move start date to the following sunday
    from_date = from_date + timedelta(days=6-from_date.weekday())
    # move end date to the previous sunday
    to_date = to_date + timedelta(days=-to_date.weekday()-1)

    # now both dates are sundays so the number is the number of weeks + 1
    nb_sundays = 1 + (to_date - from_date).days / 7   
    return nb_sundays 

print(number_of_sundays("2022/08/28", "2022/09/20"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, However that is not the issue at hand. You did help out with the logic. But I need the dates to be able to be any date and not to move the days to the following sunday. Ex. if start date is a Wed 01/05/2022, and end date is Monday 01/24.2022, I need a program to calculate the 3 Sunday's inbetween!

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to upvote or to accept answer! Although the help is still greatly appreciated!

Comment: @PedroRodrigues that's exactly what it does ! input any dates and it'll give you the number of sundays in between, which was your original question, per the title of this article. I was explaining to you how the program works. Just read it, try to understand it, and comment later.

Comment: so change the parameters in my example : print(number_of_sundays("2022/01/05", "2022/01/24")) returns 3 as expected

Comment: I apologize for not testing your solution after reading! Your response was in fact the solution i needed! I would like to thank you! I hope to have enough rep to upvote you soon!

Comment: @PedroRodrigues You don't need a specific rep to accept an answer... that would be counter-productive. See here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362336/require-reputation-for-answer-not-for-comment